# dotNet iEquatyComparer doesn't get called by HashSet(of T)

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to implement a HashSet of custom objects but the object specific GetHashCode and Equals implementations never get called.  Note - this is NOT a school project but is a database clean up where several people did parts of the work and I need to complete the analysis.  Code is below and in VB.Net (same problem occurs in VS 2010, 2013, and 2015)

```
Imports HashSet_testing

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Const Source As String = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy red dog"

        Dim stringhash As New HashSet(Of String)(Source.Split(" "c))
        stringhash.UnionWith(Source.Split(" "c))
        Debug.Print(String.Join(" ", stringhash))

        Dim WordHash As New HashSet(Of word)
        For Each s As String In Source.Split(" "c)
            WordHash.Add(New word(s))
        Next s
        ' Second pass; should load nothing
        For Each s As String In Source.Split(" "c)
            WordHash.Add(New word(s))
        Next s
        Debug.Print(String.Join(" ", WordHash))

    End Sub

End Module

Class word
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of word), IEqualityComparer

    Private _word As String = ""

    Public Sub New(word As String)
        _word = word
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _word
    End Function

    Public Function Equals1(x As word, y As word) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of word).Equals
        Debug.Print("Equals({0}, {1} called", x, y)
        Return x._word.Equals(y._word)
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As word) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of word).GetHashCode
        Debug.Print("GetHashCode1({0}}", obj)
        If TypeOf obj IsNot word Then Return 0
        Return _word.GetHashCode()
    End Function

    Private Function Equals2(x As Object, y As Object) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer.Equals
        Debug.Print("Equals2({0}, {1})", x, y)
        If TypeOf x Is word AndAlso TypeOf y Is word Then
            Return (Equals1(CType(x, word), CType(y, word)))
        Else
            Return x.Equals(y)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode2(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode
        Debug.Print("GetHashCode2{{0})", obj)
        If TypeOf obj Is word Then Return GetHashCode1(obj) Else Return obj.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an `IEqualityComparer` with a `HashSet`, you must pass the `IEqualityComparer` to the constructor of the `HashSet`.  That is why your methods are not being called here.

```
Dim WordHash As New HashSet(Of word)(New word("X"))
```

Based on the way your code is written I think you might be confusing `IEqualityComparer(Of T)` with `IEquatable(Of T)`.  The former is typically used when you want to change the way a class is compared for equality without changing that class itself.  For example, if the target of the comparison is `Word` you would have a separate `WordEqualityComparer` class.  That is also why you have to pass it to the constructor of the `HashSet`.

In your code, it looks like you're really intending to implement the comparison logic in the target class itself.  In that case, you should *override* the base class `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your `word` class, and optionally implement `IEquatable(Of word)`.  If you do this, you do not need to pass anything to the constructor of the `HashSet` and your methods will be called by default as expected.

```
Class word
    Implements IEquatable(Of word)

    Private _word As String = ""

    Public Sub New(word As String)
        _word = word
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _word
    End Function

    Public Function Equals1(w As word) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of word).Equals
        Debug.Print(String.Format("Equals1({0}) called on {1}", w, Me))
        Return Me._word.Equals(w._word)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Debug.Print(String.Format("Equals({0}) called on {1}", obj, Me))
        If TypeOf obj Is word Then
            Return Equals1(CType(obj, word))
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Debug.Print(String.Format("GetHashCode() called on {0}", Me))
        Return Me._word.GetHashCode()
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Brian,

Thanks.  I was misreading the documentation on HashSet.  Problem solved and I didn't have to implement the iEquityComparer.  Just overriding the Equals and GetHashCode functions did the job.